# Socket communication in android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am a newbiee in socket communication....android client, 
I am facing a problem to communicate my android client to C# server using TCP protocol only so that i can when my server queries some data or information to the android client, the client responds back. communication will be over Wi-fi.

plz guide.
Any help is appreciated...

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

has plenty of docs on how Android does that -- there is no shortage of stuff ready